# How do I know to which MacOS version a certain system package header belongs?

Tags: macos, header-files

For example, for headers and source files located in `security_systemkeychain-55202` [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55202/src/) or `Security-58286.20.16` [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-58286.20.16/), how do I know which MacOS version is compatible or is to be used with them ? And what do these differet versions mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start at the top level of opensource.apple.com, pick a desired version of macOS, and search for the package name. So, for example: https://opensource.apple.com/ -> click 10.14.1 under macOS -> https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10141.html -> search for "security_systemkeychain" -> finds [security_systemkeychain-55207.50.1](https://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55207.50.1/).

I don't know of a way to go in the reverse direction, from a specific version of a package to the corresponding version of macOS.

The package versions are not meaningful externally to Apple.